# Asp.Net Login Page , What would be the best approach

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using `Asp.Net/C#` and `Visual Studio 2008` to build an application.Right now I want to create a login page for my application , I would like to ask you guys , what would be the best approach to it.Should I go with `Forms Authentication in Asp.Net` or Should I try looking at `Ajax Login` with `Asp.Net`.Which would be more appropriate.If possible please let me know some of the pros and cons of the approaches.Also could anyone suggest me some links for a good starting point.
Any suggestions are most welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to go for Forms Authentication. below is advantages of it.

```
1) users do not have to be member of a domain-based network to have access to your application. 
2) Web applications, particularly commercial sites where customers order products, want to have access to user information. Forms authentication makes these types of applications easier to create.
3) Keep personalization cookies that contain user-specific preferences and non-sensitive data separate from authentication cookies.
4)Consider reducing the cookie lifetime to reduce the time window in which an attacker can use a captured cookie to gain access to your application with a spoofed identity.
```

List the steps to use Forms authentication in a web application?

```
1.Set the authentication mode in Web.config to Forms.
2.Create a Web form to collect logon information.
3.Create a file or database to store user names and passwords.
4.Write code to add new users to the user file or database.
5.Write code to authenticate users against the user file or database.
```

Hope this info is helpful to you make decision

Answer (score 0):

Use [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) for login.

It has ASP.net binding too..
 http://oauth.net/code/